# Error when switching from Windows 11 to Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have Windows and Ubuntu installed. Both systems work properly. Switching from Ubuntu to Windows has no problems.

But when switching from Windows to Ubuntu the computer hangs up showing error message `/dev/nvme0n1p7: clean, ../.. file, ../.. blocks .. [..]` followed by the attached dump. When I turn the computer off and on again it shows `/dev/nvme0n1p7: recovering journal` and `/dev/nvme0n1p7: clean, ../.. file, ../.. blocks .. [..]`. Then Ubuntu launches properly.

Environment: Mainboard Giga Byte B760 DS3H DDR4; CPU i5-12400F; 16 GB Cache; SSD with Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS installed; HDD

Ubuntu is installed on on 3 partitions: /boot 1GB; /home 50 GB; / 30GB; and Swap 16 GB; EFI 500 MB.

`/dev/nvme0n1p7` seems to be the root partition.

I already updated GRUB, but the error still remains.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My issue is solved. Problem was that a proper Nvidia driver was missing. This led to problems when launching Ubuntu. Nvidia is a proprietary product and thus proprietary drivers are required. I switched on the indicator "install proprietary drivers", updated, rebooted an the error was gone.

Answer (score -1):

seen this before a few years ago - occured after a kernel update - fixed it by upgrading nvidia drivers and rebooting

Comment: good tip. updating the drivers helped, but now I ran into the next issue. Thanks for helping.